# Durrett Exercise 1.4.2

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> **1.4.2** Let $f\geq 0$ and $E_{n,m}=\{x: m/2^n \leq f(x) \leq (m+1) /2^n\}$. As $n \uparrow \infty$, show that:
> $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{m}{2^n} \mu(E_{m,n}) \uparrow \int f d\mu$$

I was trying to solve this exercise without any of the convergence theorems.
(To solve with Monotone convergence theorem, we only need to define $g_n=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{m}{2^n} 1_{E_{n,m}}$, which is an increasing sequence of functions that converges to $f$)

I was able to find [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3875096/the-integral-of-a-limit-of-simple-functions), which defines a simple function approximation to $f$

> $$\phi_n(x)=\begin{cases}
> m/2^n,&m/2^n\leq f(x)<(m+1)/2^n \\
> n,&f(x)\geq n
> \end{cases}
> $$

and claims that

> It is easy to show $\displaystyle \int f=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int \phi_n$.

I fail to see why this is true.

Also, the answer suggests that we could use the representation

> $$\phi_n=\sum_{m=0}^{n2^n-1}m/2^n 1_{E_{n,m}}+\sum_{m=n2^n}^\infty n 1_{E_{n,m}}$$

and finish by noting

> $$\phi_n(x) \leq g_n(x) \leq f(x)$$

Is this limit well-defined when $n \to \infty$?

Comment: At first sight, it seems to me that the proof of the claim would mirror that of Beppo Levi/Monotone convergence so it kind of defeats the purpose of not using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\psi_n:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be prescribed for $x>0$ by: $$x\mapsto \min(n,2^n\lfloor x2^{-n}\rfloor)$$For $x\leq0$ let $\psi_n(x)=0$.

If $\phi_n$ is defined as in your question then: $$\phi_n=\psi_n\circ f$$
Clearly $\psi_n$ is non-negative, measurable and has finite image and consequently this is also true for $\phi_n$.

Further $\psi_n(x)\uparrow x$ for every $x$ and consequently $\phi_n(x)\uparrow f(x)$ for every $x$.

For every $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ we have $\epsilon f\leq\phi_n$ for $n$ large enough which makes us conclude that $$\epsilon\int fd\mu=\int\epsilon fd\mu\leq\int\phi_nd\mu\leq\int fd\mu$$for $n$ large enough.

Then we have:$$\epsilon\int fd\mu\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\phi_nd\mu\leq\int fd\mu$$ for every $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ and conclude that:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\phi_nd\mu=\int fd\mu$$
Here the limit on LHS can be recognized as the summation mentioned in **1.4.2**.